# wait for another process execute in pipe()

Tags: c, operating-system

My assignment require enter a command line with a pipe char. Then print out the result after 2 execution in pipe. Use two child to process and use execvp() to execute each command. Not use one child and parent. Example:

```
 echo NULL | tr a-z A-Z
```

I already wrote my `parse()` function to split each word. 
My idea is read the first command line. When `parse()` read '|' , create a pipe, fork a first child AND WAIT. Then use `parse()` again to get 2nd child. 
I couldn't figure out how to first child wait for second child. 
Anyone can give me idea or hint?

Comment: The first child doesn't need to wait for the second child if it can complete its work without doing so.  Since their only association is the pipe, that interaction is pretty much fully mediated by the pipe.  Moreover, since the pipeline's work is not complete until the *second* process finishes, it is the second that the parent process should be waiting on.

Comment: It is operating system specific (since standard C11 don't know about pipes); so you probably need some `linux` or `POSIX` tag at least. You could parse the entire line, and make some [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of it, then interpret that AST. BTW, you should look into the source code of existing shells.

Comment: BTW, your question is unclear and lacks some [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, note that in general, the first process will write too much data to be held in the pipe, so you must start the second process and let it run before the first process completes, so that there isn't a blockage on the pipe, which has a finite (and traditionally quite small) capacity.  Classically, it was 5 KiB; these days, it's more like 64 KiB (or possibly 256 KiB). When you're sending 5 bytes, none of that matters much.  In general, you won't be sending just 5 bytes.